# Odd modrewrite behavior

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I am running Wordpress (and the buddypress plugin) in a sub directory:

```
mydomain.com/mysubdomain/
```

My modrewrites is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysubdomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysubdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything works as expected. For example, the About Us page at mydomain.com/mysubdomain/?page=2 has a "pretty" URL of mydomain.com/mysubdomain/about-us

I also have a **non-wordpress** website in my root directory at mydomain.com with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^newpage\.html$ http://mydomain.com/mysubdomain/about-us [NC,L]
```

This rewrites http://mydomain.com/newpage.html to the page at http://mydomain.com/mysubdomain/about-us - however, this displays the Wordpress' 404 page not found error. (The URL in the browser is correct: http://mydomain.com/newpage.html)

Since the Wordpress 404 page displays, this suggests the issue is with Wordpress' modrewrites conflicting with the newpage.html redirect.

Help/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule doesn't seem to be doing what you are describing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^newpage\.html$ http://mydomain.com/mysubdomain/about-us [NC,L]
```

This *redirects the browser* to http://mydomain.com/mysubdomain/about-us which doesn't line up with what seems to be happening. The problem is that the wordpress controller may not process the request correctly if you simply rewrite the URI (not sure about this, it's just a guess), so you may need to rewrite to the un-rewritten URI:

```
RewriteRule ^newpage\.html$ /mysubdomain/?page=2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jon. It sounds like you can not redirect to a "pretty" URL, so you should redirect to ?page=2, is that correct?

Comment: @user663561 Not redirecting in the last rule. The browser's address bar will still say `mydomain.com/newpage.html` but what gets served is `/mysubdomain/?page=2`. It is internally rewritten. There's no reason to make it a pretty URL if the browser never sees it.

Comment: Hi Jon,
".. the problem is that the wordpress controller may not process the request correctly if you simply rewrite the URI, so you may need to rewrite to the un-rewritten URI..."

That appears to be what is happening. Redirecting to the un-rewritten URI appears to work.